# Symfony3 - how to compare properties from 2 different entities

Tags: entity-framework, doctrine, compare, symfony

I want to create a view where an event is displayed only if it is owned by the currently logged in user. 
So I want to compare LoginID from the Events entity to the current user ID.
I tried with the following function:

```
public function showAction(Events $event, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user=$this->getUser()->getLoginid();
        $guests = $em->getRepository('VendorMyBundle:Guests')->findByEventid($id);
        $events = $em->getRepository('VendorMyBundle:Events')->findByEventid($id);
        // condition to display only events owned by the current user
        if ($events->getLoginid()==$user){
            $session = new Session();
            $session->set('eventid', $id);
            $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($event);
            return $this->render('events/show.html.twig', array(
                'event' => $event,
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
                'guests' => $guests,
            ));
        }
        $this->addFlash('error', 'The event does not exist or you do not have permission to view it.');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home_page');
    }
```

LoginID in Events entity is a Many-to-One relation property towards the Logins entity which is my user provider entity. 
When I try to view with that method in my controller I get this: *Error: Call to a member function getLoginid() on a non-object* on the line with the IF statement.
Additional question would be, how do I compare 2 property values from 2 different entities?

Comment: That mean that $events is null, so possibly $em->getRepository('VendorMyBundle:Events')->findByEventid($id); return null.

Comment: It's not null, because if I eliminate the condition and just display the event given by the route parameter it displays ok, it just doesn't check to see if the current user owns it.

Comment: I dont understand what you means with it displays ok, but be sure of that doing a var_dump($events); die(); just before the if.

Comment: I meant that it displays the event, not an empty page. I did the var_dump and it dumped me the right event values.

Comment: But the null that I say is not $event, is $events in plural, that is the var that you are doing the getLoginid() request.

Comment: sorry, typo. I dumped `var_dump($events)`. It dumped me right details.

Comment: Then whatever is in $events, is not an object with a getLoginid(), thats what your error say.

Comment: yeah, it returns an array apparently.
`array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Events)[1091]
      private 'eventname' => string 'badumptss' (length=9)
      private 'location' => string 'outer space' (length=11)
      private 'eventid' => int 5
      private 'cover' => string 'download.png' (length=12)
      private 'loginid' => int 8` <br>
How do I compare though?

Comment: I post and answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem is that you are returning an array you have two choices, update the findByEventid() to return a single result

```
return  $query->getSingleResult();
```

or

```
if ($events[0]->getLoginid()==$user){
..
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: YES! I used the 2nd option and it worked. thanks a lot !